# Initialization of static object in Windows (for a class factory)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, class-factory

I'm writing a class factory (in Visual Studio 2008) where the classes are registering themselves. The class factory is a singleton and the classes register themselfes like this:

in Factory.h

```
class Factory {...};

template<typename T>
class Register
{
public: 
    Register()
    {
        Factory::instance().register<T>();
    }
};
```

in SomeRegisteredClass.cpp

```
#include <Factory.h>

class SomeRegisteredClass : public ISomeInterface
{
};

static Register<SomeRegisteredClass> register;
```

During runtime, however, the constructor of Register never gets called and, thus, SomeClass never gets registered. I suspect that there is some Optimization going on that optimizes away the stuff in SomeRegisteredClass.cpp (since SomeClass isn't used anywhere else in the code directly, but only through its interface). Could that be and how can I disable it.

Edit1:
All this stuff is compiled into a static library, which is linked to an executable.

Comment: Indeed, global variables are a minefield, and this one isn't guaranteed to be initialised until you use a function or variable in that translation unit. I'm afraid I can't offer a constructive answer other than "don't use globals".